# How can I read the User properties saved in the File/Project properties menu?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

In the Google Apps Script editor, I can set a user property by opening the File > Project properties menu, and then selecting the "User properties" tab. However, it seems that the PropertiesService is unable to access the values set in this menu. **Is there a way I can access the values set through this menu in my script?**

1. Set {"propertyA", "valueA"} in "User Properties" tab (pictured
   below)
   [image: "User Properties" tab]
2. Run `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperties()`
3. Output: `{}`

If I were to then run `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("propertyB", "valueB");` and then `getProperties()` again, the output would update to show only `{propertyB=valueB}`.

Similarly, as my searches all direct me to the PropertiesService, where can I find documentation about these menu properties? (Specifically, I'd like to know when I should use the menu option versus setting the values programatically.)

Comment: Is this thread helpful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908799/var-userproperties-propertiesservice-getuserproperties-is-not-working-prope

Comment: @Tanaike It was, thank you. I haven't tested it, but it seems the UI is accessed via a deprecated method. Reading through that thread also inspired me to look through Google's issue tracker and, indeed, the bug was reported a few years ago and seems to have been assigned in early 2017. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36762534

Comment: Thank you for the additional information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The GUI for accessing user properties was never updated when the [UserProperties class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties) was [deprecated in 2014](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2014#february_25_2014). The issue was finally resolved with the [redesigned Apps Script IDE in 2020](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases/2020#december_7_2020), which removed the GUI for accessing properties altogether.

Although it is possible to access the legacy IDE and modify *script* properties via the menu, the only way to access user properties is programmatically with [`PropertiesServices.getUserProperties()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getuserproperties). Google has also published a [guide to the Properties service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties).