# Please tell me about how safely save access key and secret key in Properties of GoogleAppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, properties

I am developing google-sheets add-on.

I want to functions that create API-link when you input access-key and secret-key.
I think that GAS Properties realize this, but I'm anxious about security. (Unfortunately, I cannot find solutions of this......)

Can anyone give me some advices??

Answer (score 1):

### You can use [User Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getUserProperties()) instead of [Script Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getScriptProperties())

User properties refer to

> property store that only the current user can access, and only within this script.

This means for an Add-on that every user can read and and those properties are only accessible by the [active user](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/glossary#active_user).

Comment: Thanks for your advice! But User Properties is deprecated now...... Do you know any other way?? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/user-properties

Comment: Class UserProperties is deprecated is favor of `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()`. `PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty()` is the way to use it.

Comment: Oh, I see! By the way, do you know where the value is saved when I use setProperty()??

Comment: It is a hidden property store that you cannot retrieve from the UI. You can access those properties only with `get`, `set` and `delete`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24908799/var-userproperties-propertiesservice-getuserproperties-is-not-working-prope).

Comment: I got it. What's the reason that use Document Properties instead of Script Properties?I'm sorry for all of the questions......

Comment: Document Properties is interesting e.g. if the Add-on needs to store document specific properties (e.g. file ID) separately for each document.

Comment: I see. Well, I understand that there is a limit on properties storage. When the project is GAS add-on and published, the each users has this limit??(all addon users have 500kb limit on Properties total storage??)

Comment: It's `500kB / property store` - each user will have his own property store and thus his own quota.

Comment: I see how it is. Thanks for your advise. It helps me a lot! You mind if I question you sometime again?

Comment: OK! I made [a new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63741297/i-want-to-know-about-spreadsheettriggerbuilder-of-gas-when-the-project-is-add-on), so If that's all right with you, please take a look and help me again!