# I want to know about SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder of GAS when the project is add-on and published

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, eventtrigger

I am developing google-sheeets add-on.

I want to create functions that create triggers associated to individual spreadsheets.
I think that GAS [SpreadSheetTriggerBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) realize this function, but I don't know the behavior when the project is add-on and published.

Trigers that the add-on users add to each spreadsheets will be shared??

For example,
A and B install the add-on to their own spreadsheet.
A add Triger with the add-on, then B will be able to use the Triger that A add to the sheet??

Answer (score 2):

### When [building a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname) with the SpreadSheetTriggerBuilder, an installable trigger will be created

This means:

- The trigger runs under the authorization of the person who created it - and will execute the bound function on behalf of the person who installed the trigger
- In other words - if your Add-on installs an `onEdit` trigger - this trigger will fire for all users who edit the spreadsheet, but authorized as the person who installed the trigger
- However, when you build a trigger it applies only to a specific spreadsheet that you need to define,e.g.

```js
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
```

- That is if user A creates the trigger A when having spreadsheet A open and user B creates the trigger A when having spreadsheet B open - those triggers will not inferfer. Trigger A will only fire when spreadsheet A is edited, trigger B will only fire when Spreadsheet B is edited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Where Trigger A and B are saved?? The same storage??

Comment: The storage is Apps Script internal, in any case triggers for different documents are stored separately.

Comment: I see! In that case, each users have 20 limit on Triggers?? Or each Sheets??

Comment: It's 20 / user / script - not per sheet.

Comment: I cannot understand 20 / user / scrip very well,  it meens that the script has 20 limit on Triggers when it is add-on and published?? For example, userA and userB add triggers to their own spreadsheet with the same add-on, then the add-on's trigger limit become 18??

Comment: @Jamm It's 20 per user per script. Now add-on is just 1 script for all. So, it can be simplified as 20 per user. Each user will have a quota of 20 triggers for your addon.

Comment: @TheMaster  Oh, I see! By the way, defferent users add trigger to the same sheet with add-on, the trigger is shared?? For example, userA and userB add triggerA to sheetA with add-on, both of them can use triggerA on sheetA??

Comment: The trigger works for any user who uses a sheet, no matter who installed the trigger. But you have to implement in your code a conditional statement to make sure that the trigger is not installed more than once.